# How to create installer with addons

Tags: c++, .net, installation, windows-installer

How windows installers with babylon toolbar or many other addons (clickable checkboxes before installation starts) is created? Some special software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, most installers are created using a setup authoring tool. Here is a list which can get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

You can add a toolbar add-ons by simply creating a custom dialog and conditioning a feature in your package.